# SQL - Select username WHERE role = $string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table where users and their roles are stored. Users can have 1 or more role. The roles are stored in form of string where values are separated by comma following a space.

```
//Get selected roles from user input on a string where values are separated by , and space   

$roles = roleA, roleB; //  --> user selected input        
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE role IN" .$roles;
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(role, '$roles');
```

Full code below :

```
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');

$roles = array_map('trim', explode(',',$_POST['role']));
$roles_tests = array_map(function($role) use ($link) {
        $role = $link->real_escape_string($role);
        return "FIND_IN_SET('$role', role)";
    }, $roles);
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE " . implode(' OR ',           $roles_tests);
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    echo '<option value="">Please choose</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($results)); 
        var_dump($row['username']);
        echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Empty</option>'; //display when no data!
}
?>
```

Var dump results :

```
var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($results));  --> 1   
var_dump($row['username']);  --> user1
```

Even thou it says that num_rows = 1  still on the for loop it gets it as 0 and dropdown list is empty. If i try to put the conditions on `WHERE` manually it works fine.

Comment: Are you actually storing a comma-separated list in the `role` column?

Comment: And the input can also be multiple roles? Do you want to find users who have all those roles, or users who have any of them?

Comment: I did not build the db. i just have to work on it. role column is like this :                  role varchar(250)

Comment: If the user has any of the roles from the roles selected it should be pulled from db

Comment: The spaces after the commas are a real problem, they prevent `FIND_IN_SET()` from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the input up into an array of roles. Then you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()` to test each of these against the `role` column.

You also need to remove the spaces after the commas before calling `FIND_IN_SET()`, since it treats them literally.

So the query should be:

```
$roles = array_map('trim', explode(',', $_POST['role']));
$roles_tests = array_map(function($role) use ($db) {
    $role = $db->real_escape_string($role);
    return "FIND_IN_SET('$role', REPLACE(role, ', ', ','))";
}, $roles);
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $roles_tests);
```

Replace `$db` with the actual variable you're using to hold your `mysqli` database connection object.

Comment: Can u explain what this does : $role = $db->real_escape_string($role); . Right now it doesnt return anyhting and maybe i am missing something

Comment: Echo of that query is:                                                                                     SELECT username FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Financa', REPLACE(role, ', ', ',')) OR FIND_IN_SET('IT', REPLACE(role, ', ', ','))

Comment: Replace `$db` with your actual database connection variable.

Comment: did that. mine is $link

Comment: You changed it in both places, `use($link)` and `$link->real_escape_string`?

Comment: It's needed to protect from SQL injection, by escaping the input. If you're using PDO, it's easier to create a prepared statement with a dynamic number of parameters.

Comment: I removed the spaces after , . Should i change anything in here                  return "FIND_IN_SET('$role', REPLACE(role, ', ', ','))";                                                            Edited it like this "FIND_IN_SET('$role', REPLACE(role, ',', ','))";   Still not working, Doesnt return anything

Comment: Well. It was my mistake on adding another ' where it wasnt needed. Your code works like charm now. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to call `REPLACE()` if the spaces are already removed, just use `role` there.

Comment: i tried to get the list of users that i pull from db and put them on a drop down list but list comes empty. See the above code for full code

Comment: If `var_dump($row['username'])` shows the username, I don't see how the dropdown could be empty. Do you see the options if you use `View Source`? It could just be because you're creating invalid HTML by mixing debugging output with `<option>` inside the `<select>`

Comment: The only option shown is `<option value="">Empty</option>`. I also tried to echo the whole page by using `require_once` and the dropdown with data pulled from db is shown. At this point i dont even understand this anymore

Comment: I can't see how that's possible. That's printed by the `else` branch, but you said you're getting output from `var_dump($row['username'])`, which is in the `if` branch.

Comment: Are you sure this code is only running when the user submits the form with the Roles input field?

Comment: yes, the codes runs only after the user has submitted the form. Also the code runs perfectly if i try to  search for the role manually : `WHERE role = 'Financa' `

Comment: Either the `if` or `else` block runs, they can't both run during the same execution. `var_dump` is only in the `if` block, and `Empty` is only in the `else` block. It's not possible for you to get both outputs, but that's what you say is happening.

Comment: There must be something else going on that's executing the code twice, with different inputs.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is executed only once. Also as i said before code runs fine if i try to search for the role manually. Dont wanna be rude but are you sure the method u gave me is correct, in the context of  brackets or "  that is messing up the code maybe ?

Comment: I started with `$_POST['role'] == "role1,role2,role3"`, the query was `SELECT username FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('role1', role) OR FIND_IN_SET('role2', role) OR FIND_IN_SET('role3', role)`

Comment: `SELECT username FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Financa', role)`

Comment: That looks correct, I can't explain why it's not working.